# Twitter login page won't open a

Tags: java, android, api, twitter

I'm trying to intergrate twitter to my app, and every time i press login button this appears in log cat and nothing happens. the project i'm forking is https://github.com/daiweilu/TwitterLoginExample/blob/master/TwitterLoginExample

I am trying for 4 hours but no hope at all

```
05-20 21:22:41.359: W/System.err(10294): api.twitter.com
05-20 21:22:41.359: W/System.err(10294): Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
05-20 21:22:41.359: W/System.err(10294):    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=8e063946 or
05-20 21:22:41.359: W/System.err(10294):    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=ef59cf9f
05-20 21:22:41.359: W/System.err(10294): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[8e063946-ef59cf9f 8e063946-ef59cf75], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.1}
05-20 21:22:41.359: W/System.err(10294):    at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:179)
05-20 21:22:41.359: W/System.err(10294):    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:53)
05-20 21:22:41.359: W/System.err(10294):    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.post(HttpClientBase.java:82)
05-20 21:22:41.359: W/System.err(10294):    at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:116)
05-20 21:22:41.359: W/System.err(10294):    at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:98)
05-20 21:22:41.359: W/System.err(10294):    at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:287)
05-20 21:22:41.359: W/System.err(10294):    at tk.pidevelopers.floata.MainActivity$GetRequestTokenTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:87)
05-20 21:22:41.359: W/System.err(10294):    at tk.pidevelopers.floata.MainActivity$GetRequestTokenTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
05-20 21:22:41.359: W/System.err(10294):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
05-20 21:22:41.359: W/System.err(10294):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
05-20 21:22:41.359: W/System.err(10294):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
05-20 21:22:41.359: W/System.err(10294):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
05-20 21:22:41.367: W/System.err(10294):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
05-20 21:22:41.367: W/System.err(10294):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
05-20 21:22:41.367: W/System.err(10294): Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: api.twitter.com
05-20 21:22:41.367: W/System.err(10294):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:497)
05-20 21:22:41.367: W/System.err(10294):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
05-20 21:22:41.367: W/System.err(10294):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
05-20 21:22:41.367: W/System.err(10294):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:69)
05-20 21:22:41.367: W/System.err(10294):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
05-20 21:22:41.367: W/System.err(10294):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:322)
05-20 21:22:41.367: W/System.err(10294):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
05-20 21:22:41.367: W/System.err(10294):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
05-20 21:22:41.367: W/System.err(10294):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
05-20 21:22:41.367: W/System.err(10294):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:406)
05-20 21:22:41.367: W/System.err(10294):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:387)
05-20 21:22:41.367: W/System.err(10294):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
05-20 21:22:41.375: W/System.err(10294):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:614)
05-20 21:22:41.375: W/System.err(10294):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
05-20 21:22:41.375: W/System.err(10294):    at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:137)
```

additional info : I am using twitter4J 4.0.1 the latest version and used many other versions

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you can't access Twitter's API server. Are you perhaps going through a proxy? If this is the case, this might help:

Have a look [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html) under "HTTP proxy server". You need to set the ConfigurationBuilder up to work with the proxy. Something like this:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
        ...

        .setHttpProxyHost(proxyHost)
        .setHttpProxyPort(proxyPort);
```

Hope this helps.